# Laravel & Dingo: Secure API with Facebook/Google Login

Tags: facebook, laravel, oauth, dingo-api

I have developed an API in Laravel with the Dingo Framework. 
Now I want to secure API access with Facebook and/or Google Log-In (for example with OAuth)

Is there a tutorial or something like that? I don't know how to integrate the secure API access into my api.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you been able to achieve this @daniel?

Answer (score 0):

Some links that might point you in the right direction:

Dingo seems to support (https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Authentication) OAuth2 via https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server

then check these associated packages.

https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-facebook